# display information in network edges using visNetwork

Tags: r, graph

I am starting to learn about interactive graphs in R, and  I found the library `visNetwork` very helpful.

However, I don't find on the vignettes how to display a pop-up with more information than the `value` and `title` when the mouse is moved over the edge.

Using one of the examples in the documentation

```
# data used in visNetwork vignette
nb <- 10
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:nb, label = paste("Label", 1:nb),
group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], nb, replace = TRUE), value = 1:nb,
title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb,"<br>Tooltip !</p>"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

edges <- data.frame(from = c(8,2,7,6,1,8,9,4,6,2),
to = c(3,7,2,7,9,1,5,3,2,9),
value = rnorm(nb, 10), label = paste("Edge", 1:nb),
title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb,"<br>Edge Tooltip !</p>"))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "500px", width = "100%")
```

How could I add more information to the pop-up, such as, different parameters related to the edge (width, frequency, ..)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to paste all the information into the title column.

```
# data used in visNetwork vignette
nb <- 10
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:nb, label = paste("Label", 1:nb),
                    group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], nb, replace = TRUE), value = 1:nb,
                    title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb,"<br>Tooltip !</p>"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

edges <- data.frame(from = c(8,2,7,6,1,8,9,4,6,2),
                    to = c(3,7,2,7,9,1,5,3,2,9),
                    value = rnorm(nb, 10), label = paste("Edge", 1:nb))

edges$title <- paste0(edges$label, "<br> value : ", round(edges$value, 2))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "500px", width = "100%")
```